# Critical Points

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm slightly confused as to how to solve for critical points, for example:

$$f(x) = x^{3} + 3x^{2}-24x$$

You take the derivative of the function,

$$f'(x) = 3x^{2}+6x-24$$

And then solve for x,

$$3x^{2}+6x-24 = 0$$
$$3x^{2}+6x = 24$$
$$3x(x+2) = 24$$

And this is the part where I am confused, my textbook says that the critical points are -4, and 2. But I'm not understanding how these are gotten, or if there's an error in the textbook (it's known to have some mistakes in it), can anyone help clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: factor the $3x^2 +6x -24 = 0$ and find $x = 2, -4$. Clear?

Comment: I think you should [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: Surely you know the quadratic formula.

Comment: Right, I confused myself thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Critical points occur when the first derivative is equal to zero: you need to solve for the $x$ values that make the derivative zero:

$$f'(x) = 3x^{2}+6x-24 = 0 $$
$$\iff x^2 + 2x - 8 = 0$$
$$\iff (x+4)(x-2) = 0 $$

Now the derivative evaluates to zero when either factor evaluates to zero. (Factoring the LHS as we did allows us to conclude that since the product of two expression equals zero, one or both of the expressions must be equal to zero.)

This amounts to solving two equations:

$$x+4 = 0\;\; \text{ and} \;\;x - 2 = 0$$

You should obtain your desired values for $x: x = -4,\;\;x = 2$

Comment: Not all quadratic equations factor so nicely. This is when the ["quadratic formula"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) comes in handy. A quick check of the sign of the [*discriminant*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) will tell you if there rational, even if there are real, solutions. So long as the discriminant is non-zero, you'll have at least one real root.

Comment: Oops, I meant so long as the discriminant is *non-negative* you'll have at least one real root!